# Can a VPN service totally hide my computer from WiFi network discovery like no computer connected?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, wifi-configuration

There are many devices connected to WiFi router and one can easily know how many devices are connected by using various network discovery tools available for windows and Android or by brwosing router configuration webpage.How can one hide his device from network discovery? Can VPN do that? Is there any way?

Comment: No because the router device provides the physical and data layers of the OSI model so it needs to know what devices are connected so its tables are correct.

Comment: You can disable people from accessing the configuration page over a wireless network.  If you are worried about that particular threat you should do exactly that.  Why is protecting the number of devices connected to your network important to you?

Comment: @BigChris +1 for the good explanation.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I disable routers page? I don't want to protect no. of devices i just want to make sure nobody is using network "hiddenly".

Comment: People can only use their network if they are within range. If they are within range then all you have to do is use a long enough password to the configuration page AND configure your router to use an encrypted signal ( i.e. WPA2, etc. ).  How you disable the configuration page from being accessible to wireless clients to your network depends on your router, check the manual for your router, that sort of stuff is well documented.

Comment: @JerryGoyal: if all you want is to protect your WiFi being used unauthorized, it will be sufficient to set passwords for WiFi access and for access to the WiFi router. Which router are you using?